# Question about releasing object with @property @synthesize

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, getter-setter

I know many similar questions have been asked, which is why I hesitated to post this at all, but I couldn't find anything that answered my question exactly:

When I use `@property` and `@synthesize`, does `@synthesize` take care of releasing the original value for the object being set? I.e. if I have:

```
@interface SomeClass:NSObject
{
    NSObject *object;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSObject *object;
@end

@implementation SomeClass
@synthesize object;
@end
```

Is this equivalent to getting a setter method that looks like this?

```
-(void)setObject:(NSObject *)newObject
{
[object release];
object = [newObject retain];
}
```

Or do I have to somehow take care of releasing the original object myself?

Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. Setter and getter are generated for you and are well done to keep you away from memory management:

```
-(void)setObject:(NSObject *)newObject {
  if (object != newObject) {
    [object release];
    object = [newObject retain];
  }
}
```

To release your object you can call:

```
[self setObject:nil];
```

Comment: with respect to view controllers, One of the best practices asking to do self.object = nil; in viewDidUnload( ) and to do [object release]; in dealloc. As the object gets released during viewDidUnload nil assignment itself, is our release call in dealloc sent to 'nil'.

Answer (score 1):

No need to release the original object yourself, however, you need to still clean things up in `-dealloc`.